# How to get the current drawable in the ImageView and turn it into a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a dynamic, clickable `ImageView`.  Basically, once the user clicks the ImageView, s/he can add an image to be displayed inside the view.  I want to find a way to get the current image housed in the ImageView and turn it into a bitmap.

So far, this is my attempt:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable());
```

But it is giving me a `Wrong 2nd argument type` error, as it is expecting an int.

I'm keeping the post brief for now for clarity.  I can post more code per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get Bitmap with this method :

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
```

[decodeResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) gives you bitmap from resource , 
for example , if you want to read an image from drawable folder you need decodeResource but in this case you can get bitmap from imageview directly

Comment: Thank you, Koorosh.  I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you kindly give me an upvote as well?